# How to send text to username and password field in Instagram through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram, webdriverwait

Im having the error messages for a python program I got they are :

```
   C:\Users\chanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe C:/Users/chanm/OneDrive/Desktop/bot/Commenter.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/chanm/OneDrive/Desktop/bot/Commenter.py", line 133, in <module>
        com.login()
      File "C:/Users/chanm/OneDrive/Desktop/bot/Commenter.py", line 28, in login
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/']")
      File "C:\Users\chanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
        return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
      File "C:\Users\chanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
        'value': value})['value']
      File "C:\Users\chanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
      File "C:\Users\chanm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href='/accounts/login/']"}
      (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.80)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is my code that I have
Commenter.py

```
import time
import random
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot


class Commenter:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.set_window_size(700, 900)

    """closing browser"""
    def closeBrowser(self):
        self.driver.close()

    """login in to Instagram"""
    def login(self) -> object:
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/']")
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)

    """getting pictures on a hashtag page"""
    def get_pictures_on_page(self, hashtag, scrolls=int):
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/" + hashtag + "/")
        time.sleep(2)

        # gathering photos
        pic_hrefs = []
        for i in range(1, scrolls):
            try:
                self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
                time.sleep(2)
                # get tags
                hrefs_in_view = self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
                # finding relevant hrefs
                hrefs_in_view = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in hrefs_in_view if
                                 hashtag in elem.get_attribute('href')]
                # building list of unique photos
                [pic_hrefs.append(href) for href in hrefs_in_view if href not in pic_hrefs]
                # print("Check: pic href length " + str(len(pic_hrefs)))
            except Exception:
                continue
        return pic_hrefs

    """write comment in text area using lambda function"""
    def write_comment(self, comment_text):
        try:
            comment_button = lambda: self.driver.find_element_by_link_text('Comment')
            comment_button().click()
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            comment_box_elem = lambda: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@aria-label='Add a comment…']")
            comment_box_elem().send_keys('')
            comment_box_elem().clear()
            for letter in comment_text:
                comment_box_elem().send_keys(letter)
                time.sleep((random.randint(1, 7) / 30))

            return comment_box_elem

        except StaleElementReferenceException and NoSuchElementException as e:
            print(e)
            return False

    """actually post a comment"""
    def post_comment(self, comment_text):
        time.sleep(random.randint(1,5))

        comment_box_elem = self.write_comment(comment_text)
        if comment_text in self.driver.page_source:
            comment_box_elem().send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            try:
                post_button = lambda: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='Post']")
                post_button().click()
                print('clicked post button')
            except NoSuchElementException:
                pass

        time.sleep(random.randint(4, 6))
        self.driver.refresh()
        if comment_text in self.driver.page_source:
            return True
        return False

    """grab comments from a picture page"""
    def get_comments(self):
        # load more comments if button exists
        time.sleep(3)

        try:
            comments_block = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name('Xl2Pu')
            comments_in_block = comments_block.find_elements_by_class_name('gElp9')
            comments = [x.find_element_by_tag_name('span') for x in comments_in_block]
            user_comment = re.sub(r'#.\w*', '', comments[0].text)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            return ''
        return user_comment

    """have bot comment on picture"""
    def comment_on_picture(self):
        bot = ChatBot('YouTubeChatBot')
        bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
        picture_comment = self.get_comments()
        # user's comment and bot's response
        response = bot.get_response(picture_comment).__str__()
        print("User's Comment", picture_comment)
        print("Bot's Response", response)
        return self.post_comment(response)


com: Commenter = Commenter(username='username', password='password')
com.login()

for pic in com.get_pictures_on_page(hashtag='gaming', scrolls=5)[1:]:
    com.driver.get(pic)
    time.sleep(3)
    print('Posted Comment:', com.comment_on_picture())
    time.sleep(3)
```

that is the script I have the most problems I have I have tried things along the lines of changing extensions and other little things it resolved most of them now im stuck with these ones

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear, there's no element that matches `//a[@href='/accounts/login/`.

Comment: in my program files there is

Comment: Since you haven't posted the HTML that you're processing, it's impossible for anyone to tell you how to fix that.

Comment: ive checked all spelling and it still gets mad at me

Comment: I just looked at the HTML source for `www.instagram.com`, there's no `/accounts/login/` anywhere.

Comment: The login link is added by JavaScript, it's not in the HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

The *username* and *password* field within *Instagram* are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username'][aria-label='Phone number, username, or email']"))).send_keys("JRProgrammer")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name='password'][aria-label='Password']").send_keys("JRProgrammer")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Log in']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the stack trace, it says that it is failing to find the login button, so you've entered a bad selector.  I'm not really sure why you're calling that anyway, since you wouldn't want to click the login button before entering user info.

Try:

```
    def login(self) -> object:
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
        time.sleep(2)
        user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='username']")
        user_name_elem.clear()
        user_name_elem.send_keys(self.username)
        passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='password']")
        passworword_elem.clear()
        passworword_elem.send_keys(self.password)
        passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        time.sleep(2)
        login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']")  
        login_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
```